How do I disable the touch context/right click menu when using touch longpress?
How do I disable/make the context/right click menu appear as the normal mouse context/right click menu?
As you can see below, the touch menu is huge (spans from top to bottom of my screen) and since I'm quite a nimble touch-user, I don't need it. It also shows up when using pen, which is so precise that it's not needed.
I haven't been able to find any solutions when searching. I'm used to editing both about:config and userchrome.css.
I tried using: https://www.userchrome.org/firefox-89-styling-proton-ui.html#menuspacing but it doesn't seem to apply to the touch menus.
Normal context/right click menu:

Touch context/right click menu:

